# Exported makefile not working Borland 6 C++ Builder

Tags: dll, makefile, c++builder

I have been assigned a problem where Borland C++Builder 6 is used.

Building a DLL project in my development environment on my laptop works fine, and using the DLL on the target machine works fine.

The problem arises when the DLL is built on a build machine that also creates the install package. That machine uses the exported makefile from C++Builder's `.bpr` file to build the DLL. Running the same program as previously with this DLL does not work OK (a call to a constructor seems to be hanging since debug printouts after the call are never seen).

I have built the DLL using the exported makefile on my own machine too, just to test, and that DLL does not work, either.

So, in short, the DLL works fine when built in Borland C++Builder 6, but NOT when built using the exported makefile. No code changes made.

Does anybody have any ideas what the problem might be? This is a very vague question, but the problem is very strange too.

Comment: A `.bpr` file is not a makefile, so I assume you are referring to the "Export makefile" option when right-clicking on the Project Manager, is that right?  How exactly are you compiling the makefile?  What compiler are you using, what parameters, etc?

Comment: Also, what version of "make" ?  The Borland Make is considerably different to GNU Make